# For what values of x does it converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

How can i study the character of the following series?
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\,\,\frac{x^n(\sin1\cdot\sin2\cdot ...\cdot\sin n)^2}{(1+x\cos^21)\cdot(1+x\cos^22)\cdot...\cdot(1+x\cos^2n)},\qquad x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

i tray in this way
 \begin{align*}
\left|\frac{x^n(\sin1\cdot\sin2\cdot...\sin n)^2}{(1+x\cos^21)\cdot(1+x\cos^22)\cdot...\cdot(1+x\cos^2n)}\right|=\left|\frac{x^n\left(\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin k\right)^2}{\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+x\cos^2k)}\right|=\frac{|x|^n\left(\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin k\right)^2}{\left|\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+x\cos^2k)\right|};
\end{align*} 
observing
 \begin{align}
 \prod_{k=1}^{n}\left|(1+x\cos^2k)\right| > \prod_{k=1}^{n}1=1;\qquad |x|^n\left(\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin k\right)^2 <|x|^n\qquad\qquad(1)
\end{align} 
then
 \begin{align*}
 \frac{|x|^n\left(\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}\sin k\right)^2}{\left|\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{n}(1+x\cos^2k)\right|}\le|x|^n\to\mbox{converge if}\,\,\,|x|<1
\end{align*} 
But i'm not sure abuot point $(1)$

Comment: What do you mean by "character"? Do you mean, for what values of $x$ does it converge? Where did you come across this series?

Comment: yes i maen  for what values of x converge!

Comment: Good. Please edit your question accordingly, so people don't have to read the comments to understand it. Also, what tests do you know for convergence? Which ones have you tried? What happened when you tried them?

Comment: ok ... I've tried with the test of absolute convergence, and with the comparison test, but does not work ....

Comment: I edited and posted what I did

Comment: Good! So, it certainly comverges if $|x|\lt1$. Let's hope someone can figure out what happens if $|x|\ge1$.